# Why directive ng-view is not working in my case?

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-view

I am building an AngularJS app. I have the following structure:

```
--/app
-----app.js
-----index.html
-----/css(bootstrap,app.css,...)
-----/fonts
-----/css(bootstrap,app.css,...)
-----/images
-----/partials(home.html, register.html, login.html)
```

Here is my app.js file:

```
//configure the app : load module, configure route

var app = angular.module('app',['ngRoute','ngResource','ui.bootstrap']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller: 'HomeController',
        template: '/app/partials/home.html'
    }).when('/register', {
            controller: 'HomeController',
            templateUrl: '/app/partials/register.html'
        }).when('/login', {
            controller: 'HomeController',
            templateUrl: '/app/partials/login.html'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});

app.controller('HomeController', function ($scope) {
    //nothing to do time being
});
```

Here is the index.html :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My HTML File</title>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/toaster.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/loading-bar.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"> 
  <script src="libs/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/toaster.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/loading-bar.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/ui-bootstrap-0.11.0.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
 <link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div id="page">
 <!--   <header class="container"> -->
            <!-- nav bar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Crowd Recruitment</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li ng-class="{'active':isActive('/ourmagic')}"><a href="#/ourmagic">How it's work ?</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{'active':isActive('/register')}"><a href="#/register">Register</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{'active':isActive('/login')}"><a href="#/login">Login</a></li>
        <!--<li><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Login</button></li>-->
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
     <!--   </header>-->
<div ng-view></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I don't have errors in the browser but when I load the `index.html`, the `home.html` is not included. I am wondering why? The `index.html` just contains the menu but `ng-view` is not working my partial is not loaded.

Added :
Thanks I notice I have an error on the configuration of module lines `var app = angular.module('app',['ngRoute','ngResource','ui-bootstrap']);`

I removed the loading of ui-bootstrap which is in error. So my code is 
Now it works I'll see later why I am not able to load ui-bootstrap module. Thanks to @Edminsson for code you paste at Plunker

Comment: Does it work for any of the other routes?

Comment: look at ajax requests made in browser developer tools to see where requests are made. I would try removing  `/app/` in templateUrl's

Comment: I've removed /app/ in templateUrl and tested. I am sorry it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two ng-app-declarations. You should remove the one in the html-element.
You also wrote "template" instead of "templateUrl" in the configuration of "home".

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller: 'HomeController',
        templateUrl: '/app/partials/home.html'
    })
   ...
}
```

Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UfEPeEZag5v8qkEvZoKh)

Comment: The problem is not the app in templateUrl: '/app/partials/home.html'. It's the empty ng-app in <html lang="en" ng-app>. Remove this ng-app. You have another ng-app in the body-element, <body ng-app="app">. You should only have one ng-app-declaration.